# wordpress does not execute files under wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I had my site working, but for some days, if I'm trying to go to any site in my wordpress panel (/wp-admin/xxx.php), php code of pages is not executing, but printing instead. Example for wp-login.php:

```
` element. * Default 'Log In'. * @param string $message Optional. Message to display in header. Default empty. * @param WP_Error $wp_error Optional. The error to pass. Default empty. */ function login_header( $title = 'Log In', $message = '', $wp_error = '' ) { global $error, $interim_login, $action; // Don't index any of these forms add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_no_robots' ); if ( wp_is_mobile() ) add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_login_viewport_meta' );
```

It's just fragment of code. 
All pages in my main website are still working. How can I make all sites under wp-admin being executed, not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a server issue.

If you're using Apache, make sure that php5_module is enabled. You can do so using the following `apachectl -M` (you might have to sudo that command)

If you don't see php5_module enabled, then you'll need to install it. There are a number of different ways to do this, depending on the operating system your using.

PHP's documentation covers this:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: Some of PHP code is executing, so I assume that, It's something with php tags